# Отношения(одни ко многим, многие ко многим) между документами при помощи kmongo. mongodb

Tags: kotlin, mongodb, ktor

Я изучаю котлин и пишу проект, для серверной части выбрал как раз котлин, ktor и kmongo. До этого начинал писать тот же проект на spring boot, но потом узнал про ktor и стало интересно. И дело в том, что у spring data есть аннотации по типу: `@DBRef`, `@DocumentReference`, которые помогают строить связи между документами, то в kmongo я такого не нашел. Меня волнует вопрос, что будет, если в одном документе(1) у меня будет хранится id другого документа(2) и последний документ(2) я удалю, как мне правильно удалять этот id из первого документа(1)?

Comment: Ключ с ИД второго документа можно удалить... Можно записать в него `null`... При связи "многие ко многим" - можно удалить весь документ, который описывал связь документа1 с документом2, связи ведь теперь нет.

Comment: @ksa Да, это я понимаю. Но у меня есть роли, у которых есть какие-то разрешения, этих разрешений может быть много для одной роли, они хранятся в виде массива. И вот если я удалю одно разрешение, то как удалить его из всех этих массивов у ролей?

Comment: Вот есть тема про "удаление из массива" - https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.7397b4bf-64304c81-fcb3fc1b-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in%20-mongodb